# c++ gcc error: 'sqrtl' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, gcc, std, cmath

When I try to compile the following program, the compiler gives `error: 'sqrtl' is not a member of 'std'`.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << std::sqrtl(5.0) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to know why this happens, so I started experimenting.

When I remove `std::` in front of `sqrtl` the program compiles and runs fine. When I additionally remove `#include <cmath>`, the compiler gives `error: 'sqrtl' was not declared in this scope`.

At this point I am really confused. There clearly has to be a function `sqrtl` in `cmath`, but it is not a member of `std`?

When I replace `sqrtl` with `sqrt` in the original program, the program compiles and runs fine. Same thing when I remove `std::` in front of `sqrt`. When I additionally remove `#include <cmath>`, the compiler gives `error: 'sqrt' was not declared in this scope`.

Finally, I did the same test with `sqrtf`. The same thing happened as with `sqrtl`.

Another thing I find weird is that removing `std::` lets the program compile in the first place. Especially with `sqrt` which must be a member of `std` or the compiler would have given the same error as `sqrtl` and `sqrtf`. This is especially confusing since removing `std::` in front of `cout` makes the compiler give me `error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope`.

Can anyone explain why `sqrtl`, `sqrt` and `sqrtf` behave so strangely? Is `sqrt` even a member of `std`? How could I find out whether a certain method is a member of `std` or not?

I know removing `std::` is an easy fix, but for consistency purposes I like to have `std::` in front of all `std` members in my personal library.

Comment: What version of gcc you are using? Do you need to enable c++11 support?

Comment: When in doubt, you can look it up on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt).

Comment: The reason removing `std::` works is probably because it falls back to the standard functions provided by C. Note that `std::sqrt` has several overloads and will use the right "version" of `sqrt` for the type provided.

Comment: @Slava http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/638d5ee7e9ed4869

Comment: Woot, MSVS wins the conformance race today: https://godbolt.org/z/X3-yEH

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Where does it give the appropriate information on cppreference?

Comment: @SmileyCraft It shows that `sqrtf` and `sqrtl` are both part of `namespace std` and are provided by `<cmath>` since C++11. It covers a good part of the question. The missing element seems to be that it looks like this is due to a bug in the standard library implementation (assuming you are compiling with C++11 or later).

Comment: @Slava I feel so stupid, I can not figure out which version of gcc I am using. I am using CodeBlocks and MinGW64 and I can not figure out where I can find which version of gcc I am using. But I know for a fact that lambda expressions are working, so it has to be c++11 or later.

Comment: @SmileyCraft If you are compiling for C++11 or later then there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux [Except it wont compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/458af0cf063aca1f)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Right, it says `std::sqrtl` on the title of the webpage... This makes me even more confused about my error.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, but I thought that part was clear from earlier comments. But maybe it wasn't. I was trying to express that the problem is not with the code itself.

Comment: @SmileyCraft -- `gcc --version` from the command line.

Comment: `gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug.  Per [[cmath.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cmath.syn) `sqrtl` is a member of the `std` namespace.

> ```
> namespace std {
>       [...]
>       float sqrt(float x);  // see [library.c]
>       double sqrt(double x);
>       long double sqrt(long double x);  // see [library.c]
>       float sqrtf(float x);
>       long double sqrtl(long double x);
>       [...]
> }
> ```

This is legal code and will compile in [MSVS](https://godbolt.org/z/X3-yEH) and [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xP8gMLEk0pDYNQqu).

There is a [bug report for this in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700) but it has not yet been taken care of since it is very trivial and their resources are finite.

Comment: @Amadeus Thanks for that.  I forgot compiler explorer uses libstdc++ for both clang and gcc.  Wandbox uses libc++ for clang and libc++ does not have this bug.

Comment: Does that mean I can not access `std::sqrtl`? In the comments @FrançoisAndrieux mentions that `sqrtl` falls back to the standard functions provided by C. Does this even make a difference?

Comment: @SmileyCraft It means that in gcc you can't use `std::sqrtl` because they haven't implemented it yet.  You can use just `sqrtl` though.

Comment: @SmileyCraft You can use `std::sqrt` instead, it will use the right overload for the argument type. If you *really* want to explicitly use `sqrtl` an alternative to using the global scope function from C by using `std::sqrt` and either casting the argument to `long double` or using a `long double` literal. `std::sqrt(5.0l)` or `std::sqrt(static_cast<long double>(5.0))` work.